# What is the scores calculated from the score function in SelectKBest algorithm? Do they return P value, F score, or others?

Tags: regression, feature-selection, scoring-rules

I am wondering that how the scores in Select K Best be calculated? I applied the SelectKBest with f_regression as score function. According to the documentation of SelectKBest(https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html) and f_regression(https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression.html#sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression), the score seems to be p_value. However, the model return the score are >1, and this make me think it is none of P value or F score.

Any one have idea that what is this score math formula, and how can we interpret it ? Thanks!

Comment: I am also trying to find the answer to this question, but what i can only interpret is that **f_regression** scoring function is performing Univariate linear regression and f-score is calculated using ANOVA test. But there is nothing after that to interpret the calculated scores.